# Friends and persons

Tags: probability

Three friends and seven other people are randomly seated in a row.

- What is the probability that the three friends will sit next to each other?

$\frac{8}{\binom{10}{3}}$

- What is the probability that exactly two of the three friends will sit next to each other?

I don't understand why the solution is $\frac{\binom{3}{2}[2\cdot 7\cdot 2!\cdot 7!+7\cdot 6\cdot 2!\cdot 7!]}{10!}$. Knowing that I have $10$ ways to arrange the persons, I select two of three friends with $\binom{3}{2}$ and I arrange them with $2!$. Then I arrange the other seven persons with $7!$. What I don't understand is the rest. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It says "exactly 2". That means, not all 3 of them may sit together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, pick two friends, this yields $\binom{3}{2}$. Then arrange them, this yields a factor of $2!$. Then, note that the "exactly" means the third not-picked friend should not sit next to the other two friends. There are two main cases. Either the two friends are positioned at an extremity, in which case the third friend can sit in $7$ possible spots, or he can sit in $6$ possible spots. Therefore, the number of possibilities is

$$\binom{3}{2}2!(\color{green}{7}\times7!\times\color{red}{2}+\color{green}{6}\times7!\times\color{red}{7})$$

the red part is the placement of the two friends (two possibilities for extremities, seven otherwise), the $7!$ accounts for the permutations of the remaining $7$ people, and the green part are the possible spots for the third friend.

so the probability is

$$\frac{\binom{2}{3}2!(7\times7!\times2+6\times7!\times7)}{10!}$$